# Variables not global even though being globaly defined

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, global

A website I am making has a startup function that includes a call to another function to change add to or change a global variable and update an element in the HTML document to the value.

```
function moneyUpdate (x,z){
    var k;

    if (z == 1){
        k = money + x;
        money = k;
        document.getElementById("moneyPrint").innerHTML ="$"+ k;
    }
    if (z == 0){
        money = x;
        document.getElementById("moneyPrint").innerHTML="$"+ money; 

    }
```

I call the function line this

```
//other code
moneyUpdate(1000,0);
```

and declare the variable like this

```
var money=0
```

I'm new to java script so bare withe my probable incompetence.
It prints'x' fine put it doesn't set the value of 'money' to 1000 and calling it up with y=1 doesn't add to 'money'.
I have no clue what to even  try.

Comment: Where are you using `money` in your code?

Comment: Sorry I changed it i was messing with the variable in and effort to fix it and it copy pasted as this anytime you see m it should be money

Comment: You are not giving us enough information with your little snippets. What you have should work. I also don't know what what `y=1` is supposed to do, you're not using `y` in your code...

Comment: You can embed working Javascript snippets right here on the page with the `<>` looking button in the editor. Please produce a complete example that demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: sorry I must have miss typed, i ment z=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your other code, try;

> money = moneyUpdate(1000,0);

Comment: `moneyUpdate` doesn't return anything

Comment: Are your variable declared correctly using semicolon?

Comment: Seems to have worked let me test the "1" part of the function

Comment: Yes I used a semicolon in the variable decaration

Comment: Update: fixed the return both parts of the fuction have a return value of what they print. Now the '1' part of the function woln't add to the the variable